# Display elements of List in Visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, controller-extension

I have a skill_Review__c object which has two lookup fields in them - Skills__c and Level__c.

Below is my VF and controller. I am trying to get the user input on level field by clicking the edit button VF page and when I save it the level entered by user should be updated to the Level__c on skill_review__c object.

I have created a skillreview list where I store the level__c and skill__c for a particular skill_review__c object. How can I display the skillreviewlist in my VF page and how can I update the level__c record from the value entered from level drop down list.

VFpage:

```
<apex:page standardController="Interview__c" extensions="SkillReviewExtension" showHeader="false">

  <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="Technical Skill Evaluation" id="skills_list">

           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>

 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReviewList }" var="rt" > 
 <apex:column value="{!rt.SkillReview.Skill__c}"/>
 <apex:column value="{! rt.SkillReview.Level__c}"/>
 <apex:column headerValue="Level">
                    <apex:selectList value="{!rt.level}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}">
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                        <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
  </apex:column>                  
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller extension:

```
public class SkillReviewExtension{

    private final Interview__c review;
    public  boolean IsEditMode {get;private set;}
    public String Level{get;set;}
    public List<SkillReview> SkillReviewList{get;set;}



     public SkillReviewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.review= (Interview__c)stdController.getRecord();

        initSkillReviews();
     }

    private void initSkillReviews() {
        skillReviewList=new List<skillReview>();

        for(Skill_Review__c sr: [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id ]){

            skillReviewList.add(new SkillReview(sr));
        }

    }




    public PageReference save(){
        isEditMode=false;
        skillReviewList[0].SkillReview.Level__c=Level;
        update SkillReviewList[0].SkillReview;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference edit(){
        isEditMode=true;
        return null;
    }  





}
```

SkillReview class:

```
public class SkillReview{

    public Skill_Review__c SkillReview{get;set;}

    public String Level{get;set;}


    public SkillReview(Skill_Review__c skillReview){

         this.skillReview = skillReview;
         this.Level = skillReview.Level__c;

    }

//skillReview.Level__r.Name;


}
```

Skill_review__c object has skill__c and level__c as a lookup field in it.

Comment: Rdvsm. if you want the user input then it should be in `<apex:inputText value="fieldAPIName" />` this way you can bind the value

Comment: Do you mean using it like -  <apex:selectList value="Level__c" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!isEditMode}"> in VF page? This give an error.

Comment: Just a background - I have a select list on my page with values 1 to 5. When the user select this list and click save on VF page , the level__c object should get updated. This is my requirement.

Comment: sfdcweb- please see the edited VF page.

Comment: Rdvsm -- looks like `lebel__c` is lookup field. If yes then what should happens you select `1` in picklist and is there any `Level__c` record with name or something unique `1` ? ... based on selected picklist value we can query the `Level__c` record Id and then we can assign that Id to `SkillReview.Level__c`.. after that we can perform Update DML on `SkillReview` record.

Comment: Yes Level__c is a lookup field. When I select 1 in picklist then it should update the level__c lookup field on skill_review__c object. Yes Level__c has 1,2,3,4,5 stored in it and level picklist has 1,2,3,4,5 values that can be selected. Can you please let me know the syntax to implement this? I modified my controller a bit please take a look. I am trying to update the level__c in skill_review__c object of list skilreviewlist and then trying to update the record back to database in save method.

Comment: Rdvsm. you need Id for assigning to `SkillReview.Level__c` field. So we need to query `Level__c` records based on picklist value ie. 1,2,3,4,5 anything.. I just wanted to know how you can related 1,2,3,4,5 with `Level__c` records ?

Comment: Can we continue this on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37089/discussion-between-sfdcweb-and-rdvsm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in chat. `Level__c` records Name field is 1,2,3,4,5

So what you can do

In save method Query `Level__c` records based on selected picklist value. and then update the Skill review level field with that Id

```
public PageReference save(){
        isEditMode=false;
         //set to add all the picklist level values
        set<String> setLavelNames = new set<String>();
        //iterate over wrapper class and collect all the selected level in set
        for(SkillReview obj: skillReviewList)
        {
            setLavelNames.add(obj.level);// add selected level into set 
        }
        map<String, Id> mapLevelNameToLevelId = new map<String, Id>();
        //query on Level records based on above set and create a map to hold Level Name to Id 
        for(Level__c objLevel:[SELECT Id, Name FROM Level__c WHERE Name IN: setLavelNames])
        {
            // store Name and Id of level in map as key value pair so we can get the Id in next for loop
            mapLevelNameToLevelId.put(objLevel.Name, objLevel.Id);
        }
        // perform update DML outside of for loop
        List<Skill_Review__c > lstSkillReviewToUpdate = new List<Skill_Review__c>();
        for(SkillReview obj: skillReviewList)
        {
            // get the Id from map based on selected picklist value 
            obj.SkillReview.Level__c = mapLevelNameToLevelId.get(obj.level); 
            lstSkillReviewToUpdate.add(obj.SkillReview);
        }
        update lstSkillReviewToUpdate; //update list 
        return null;
}
```